# How to use angular 'title' API?

Tags: angular

I want to get or set title of my page dynamically. I found [this](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Title) but i don't know how to using it.

Comment: You need to show at least some effort in order for someone to take time out of their day to help you here.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/set-document-title first google search of 'angular title service'. Can pple srsly be that lazy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
export class AppComponent {
  public constructor(private titleService: Title ) { }

  public setTitle( newTitle: string) {
    this.titleService.setTitle( newTitle );
  }
}
```

Source: https://angular.io/guide/set-document-title

Comment: Omg,, how can this is not showed up in side menu? Thanks man, you are save my live,,

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straightforward. In your component where you want to manipulate title add the following:

**component.ts**

```
constructor(private documentTitle: Title) {
    documentTitle.setTitle('Whatever title you want');
}
```